# Is there any 'alias' feature in SVN like we have in CVS?

Tags: svn, cvs, alias

I am migrating to SVN from CVS. In CVS I have various aliases defined in CVSROOT/Modules file. That helps me to checkout multiple directories in one go.

For example:

Defined alias in CVSROOT/Modules file as below

=--------------------------------------------------------------------------=

my_alias /dir1 /dir2 /dir3 /dir4 /dir5 /dir6

=--------------------------------------------------------------------------=

So my checkout comamnd is optimized from

$cvs co /dir1 /dir2 /dir3 /dir4 /dir5 /dir6

to

$cvs co my_alias

I want to know if there is any similar feature in SVN.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144191/svn-1-3-vs-1-5-latest might help

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should think about combine them into a single folder instead of different ones.